# Snmp4j Walk Different Results

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have a problem about the snmp walk behaving differently between platforms(same network). For example, on my windows 7 laptop, snmp walk request return with 200 results but on solaris 10 server machine, it returns with 30 results. Are there any limitations between platforms?

Comment: Just different amount of data on each platform, don't you think?

Comment: i realised that i didn't prepare the question nicely, sorry for that. I'm targeting the same snmp device from these platforms. When i browse the device with mib browser there are 200 values for the oid. I'm getting the correct result in windows 7 when implement snmp walk request from my application but couldn't manage with solaris.

Comment: SNMP usually uses UDP which is unreliable.  That could be it.  Or is it timeing out?

Comment: Actually i was using the same snmp session for the request. When i opened new session for all request seperately, i worked like a charm! Thanks for the interest :)

Comment: are they the same program working the different platforms?

Comment: yes, the same application